# Output top n records for the last hour every minute

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

What is the best way to keep updated table containing top n records for the last let's say 60 minutes for a stream using Spark Structured Streaming? I only want to update my table once a minute. I thought I would achieve this using `window` function, set window duration to 60 minutes and slide duration to 1 minute. The problem is I get data for all the sliding windows in the output, but I only need the last completely calculated (closed) window. Is there a way to achieve this? Or perhaps should I tackle the problem (keeping nearly real-time rankings for the past hour) in a different way?

My incomplete solution:

```
val entityCounts = entities
  .withWatermark("timestamp", "1 minute")
  .groupBy(
    window(col("timestamp"), "60 minutes", "1 minute")
      .as("time_window"),
    col("entity_type"),
    col("entity"))
  .count()
```

```
val query = entityCounts.writeStream
  .foreachBatch( { (batchDF, _) =>
    batchDF
      .withColumn(
        "row_number", row_number() over Window
          .partitionBy("entity_type")
          .orderBy(col("count").desc))

      .filter(col("row_number") <= 5)
      .select(
        col("entity_type"),
        col("entity"),
        col("count").as("occurrences"))
      .write
      .cassandraFormat("table", "keyspace")
      .mode("append")
      .save
  })
  .outputMode("append")
  .start()
```

Comment: The data is really simple - the columns are ['entity', 'entity type', 'timestamp']. They are just occurrences of entities in tweets. I'd like to keep updated table of entities with the most occurrences for past 60 minutes.